# Step by Step Instruction for redirect a port in cmd

Tags: client, client-server, chat

i am trying to do my first super simple chat application in android.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [1]: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/

I did everything as described but under Point 5. i lack some basics. There is written 
i shall redirect the port:

> 5.)   Redirect the port :
>   i) run -> cmd -> telnet localhost 5554
>   ii) redir add tcp:5000:6000

But my problem is i have no idea how to use the cmd, never did it before and need now something like a super Step-by-Step-Instruction for Dummies who never opened before the cmd and shall now redirect a port. Can anybody help me???